# How can I stop all alive threads from running

Tags: java, multithreading

So I'm wrapping my head around multithreading and I made a very basic program to play around with. The idea is simply I would start a couple of threads, and each would race down (decrement) to zero at which point one would be declared the winner and the others would stop immediately. I have used a boolean flag, which terminates the other threads but sometimes they carry on for a bit (I guess until they do the check in the while loop to see if run is still true).

I have tried interrupts but my understanding is that these only work on threads that are sleeping, awaiting etc, and the threads I am using a pretty much running the whole time. I have used system.exit(1) but this doesn't stop them either, at least not immediately. Just wondering what more experienced people would do? Basically I just want a thread to say "OK everybody stop what you are doing RIGHT NOW".

Here is the code:

**Runnable Class**

```
public class ThreadRunnable implements Runnable {

    private static boolean run;
    private int tick;

    public ThreadRunnable() {
        run = true;
        tick = 5;
    }

    public void run() {
        Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
        while (run) {
            tickDeduction();
            if (tick == 0) {
                System.out.println("Thread " + (Thread.currentThread().getId()) + " WINS");
                this.run = false;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void tickDeduction() {
        System.out.println("Thread " + (Thread.currentThread().getId()) + " is at tick " + this.tick);
        this.tick--;
    }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadRunnable runnableBlue = new ThreadRunnable();
        ThreadRunnable runnableRed = new ThreadRunnable();
        Thread teamBlue = new Thread(runnableBlue); 
        Thread teamRed = new Thread(runnableRed);
        teamBlue.start();
        teamRed.start();
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you make `run` a `private static volatile boolean`? Also, you shouldn't do `this.run` if `run` is `static`. Use `ThreadRunnable.run`.

Comment: Doesn't static do that?

Comment: Nope. `static` simply means that the member is a class-level member. `volatile` does something different.

Comment: Nope still does it I get something like this: Thread 9 is at tick 5
Thread 9 is at tick 4
Thread 9 is at tick 3
Thread 9 is at tick 2
Thread 8 is at tick 5
Thread 9 is at tick 1
Thread 8 is at tick 4
Thread 9 WINS
Thread 8 is at tick 3

Comment: So as you can see it is stopping, just after it checks for the boolean value, but I was wondering if it is possible to stop it immediately.

Comment: Well, the thing is that the output is synchronized, so a thread might be blocked on it waiting to print. So it could be Thread 8 is waiting for Thread 9 to finish printing, after which it can print. *Then* it checks `run`, sees that it is `false`, then exits. So your guess was in the right direction.

Comment: Well, the facetious answer is `System.exit(0);`. However, you might want to look into `FutureTask` (and [FutureTask#cancel(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) specifically).

Comment: Aaah I see. Well I kind of need that method to be synchronised or all hell breaks lose and the threads don't listen to me anymore.

Comment: So what if I put an if statement in the method, so that it returns out of the method if the run value has been declared false?

Comment: You'd still have a race condition of sorts. The thing is that the thread would block on the `System.out.println(...)` call, so any checks you make before you print would *reduce* the chances of errant behavior, but not eliminate it completely.

Comment: No that didn't work either:(

Comment: @Danrex, on the site note, do you need `tickDeduction` to be `synchronized`? There is only on thread accessing a given `Runnable object`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the behavior it seems you're looking for has actually been removed, as it isn't safe to have around (and won't work the way you want it too, either). What is it that you need done that threads have to stop immediately?

Comment: So I just want all output to stop. Once the thread 'wins' I want all other threads to either stop what they are doing, or just not print anything.

Comment: @Danrex You're thinking about this wrong. Don't think, "how can I reach into the thread and make it stop". Think, "how can I code the thread so that I don't need to reach into it to make it do, or not do, things."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically I just want a thread to say "OK everybody stop what you are doing RIGHT NOW".

There is no way for a Java application to do that to itself.   A debugger might be able to do it though.  (Certainly, the JDWP protocol has a command to freeze all threads in the target JVM ...)

---

The closest you could get within a Java application would be to traverse the tree of ThreadGroups and Threads and apply the deprecated `Thread.suspend()` method to each Thread.  (Take care to not pause the current thread ...)  But the suspend method is dangerous (see the javadocs), and there is no guarantee that you will see all threads in the traversal.  And of course, this (hypothetical) procedure is not instantaneous.

Comment: Ok well I can accept that if I can't do it then I can't do it.

Comment: Well, there *technically* is. But if I remember correctly the methods to do that were deprecated some time ago because they were unsafe to use.

Comment: @user3580294 - No, even that won't work.  1) You can only stop / pause the threads one at a time ... not all at once like the OP wants.  2) If you stopped / paused all of the threads, the thread that did the act would also be stopped / paused, and would be unable to unpause.

Comment: Yeah I didn't use the stop method because it had been deprecated. Well I'm ok with it if it can't be done. I was just wanting to make sure it wasn't anything I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Use a flag that can be claimed only once, and only first time. One such thing is an `AtomicBoolean` with a `compareAndSet()` method. To stop other threads you can send an `interrupt()`.

(Java used to have powers to stop and kill threads, but that leads to issues. Interrupts are the only reliable methods to throw a thread off its normal execution.)

https://ideone.com/1F3bkH

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        final Thread[] runners = new Thread[5];

        final Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < runners.length; i++){
            runners[i] = new Thread("Runner # " + i){
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // wait for random time
                        Thread.sleep(1000 + random.nextInt(1000));

                        // try to claim the flag
                        boolean claimed = flag.compareAndSet(false,true);

                        if(claimed){
                            System.out.println(this.getName() + " has won the race.");

                            // interrupt others
                            for (Thread t : runners){
                                if(!t.equals(this)){
                                    t.interrupt();
                                }
                            }
                        }else {
                            System.out.println(this.getName() + " has very closely lost the race.");
                        }

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        System.out.println(this.getName() + " has lost the race.");
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        // get set go
        for (int i = 0 ; i < runners.length; i++){
            runners[i].start();
        }
    }
}
```